# How can I factorise $x^2-2x-1$ into $(x-\sqrt{2}-1)(x+\sqrt{2}-1)$?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring

I have seen that $x^2-2x-1$ can be factorised into $(x-\sqrt{2}-1)(x+\sqrt{2}-1)$.

What process do I have to do to get to the factorised form of the polynomial? What is this technique called?

Comment: $$\begin{align}x^2-2x-1&=(x^2-2x+1)-1-1\\&=(x-1)^2-2\\&=(x-1)^2-(\sqrt{2})^2\\&=((x-1)+\sqrt{2})((x-1)-\sqrt{2})\end{align}$$ The second equation (a step called *completing the square*) consists in forming a trinomial $a^2+2ab+b^2$, which is equal to $(a+b)^2$. The last equation is using the factorization $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.

Comment: You find the roots of the polynomial (using the quadratic formula). Let $u$ and $z$ be these roots. Then the polynomial is factorized as $(x-u)(x-z)$. If there is one root then the factorization is $(x-u)^2$ where u is the one and only root. If there is no root there is no factorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any polynomial $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$ can be factored into a product of linear factors in terms of its roots, $r_1,\cdots,r_n$ (which may be complex numbers and they may not be distinct). Note that $f$ is of the $n^{th}$ degree, and thus has $n$ roots.

This is known as the "fundamental theorem of algebra," and lets us rewrite $f$ as so:

$$f(x) = a_n (x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots (x-r_n)$$

In your case, $f(x) = x^2 - 2x - 1$. Being a degree-$2$ polynomial, it has two roots, and it has a leading coefficient of $1$, i.e. the $a_n$ in our previous expression is $1$. Therefore,

$$f(x) = (x-r_1)(x-r_2)$$

What are $r_1,r_2$? These are, again, the roots of your quadratic. You can find these via the method of your choice, but odds are, considering the result, you'll need to use the quadratic formula to get there. But once you know the two roots, you can substitute them into the above formula and get the desired expression (perhaps with a little simplification).

Answer (score 1):

Find its roots. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of a monic quadratic polynomial $x^2+ax+b$, then$$x^2+ax+b=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta).$$More generally, if the roots of the $n$<sup>th</sup> degree monic polynomial $P(x)$ are $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$, then$$P(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\ldots(x-\alpha_n).$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by completing the squared. What do we need to complete $x^2-2x$ to be a perfect squared? We take half the coefficient of $x$ and square it. Half of $2$ is $1$.
\begin{align}x^2-2x-1&=x^2-2x+1^2-1^1-1\\&=x^2-2x+1-2\\&=(x-1)^2-2\end{align}
It is now a difference of squares which could be factor with
$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$
$$(x-1)^2-2=(x-1-\sqrt2)(x-1+\sqrt2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Solve the equation $x^2-2x-1=0$ and get $x=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{4+4}}{2}=1\pm \sqrt{2}$. This gives the factors.

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to impose $x^2-2x-1=0$ and so: $$x=\frac{2\pm2\sqrt{2}}{2}=1\pm\sqrt{2}$$
By the riules of factoring, we have:
$$(x-1-\sqrt{2})(x-1+\sqrt{2})$$